# Flexbox 100% height within non-flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider following pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVgevE

Our flex markup, `<right-component>` is inside a chunk of third party layout, namely in a div with an unrestricted height.

The div itself is inside an outer flexbox layout.

How do I make the inner flex component fill the available height without hardcoding it, or completely overriding all styles of the third party component to make it flexbox-driven?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have right-content fill the space. If so, this jsFiddle may contain the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/crfz66jx/

You have a root with height set to 100vh, so by creating a container like rightComponent and setting that to the same height, we can have the content fill 100% of the space.

CSS:

```
#rightComponent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right-content {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #779;
  height:100%
}
```

HTML:

```
<uncontrollable-third-party-component>
  <div>Third party stuff</div>
  <div id="rightComponent">
        <div id="right-topbar">
          Right topbar
        </div>
        <div id="right-content">
          Right content
        </div>
  </div>
</uncontrollable-third-party-component>
```

Comment: `right-component`'s height is not 100vh, it's 100vh minus the unknown height of the 3rd party content above